# Conditions for an element to be an unit element in a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

Say $R$ is a ring with unit element $1$ and $\phi:R\to R'$ is a ring homomorphism. Prove that $\phi(1)$ is unit element of $R'$.

So I have shown the following with regard to $\phi(1)$

$$\phi(1)\cdot\phi(a)=\phi(a)\cdot\phi(1)=\phi(a)$$
$$ \phi(-1)=-\phi(1)$$

Is this sufficient, or there is something more I need to prove?

Comment: Is $\phi$ onto?

Comment: If your definition of ring homomorphism doesn't include the condition that $\phi(1)=1$, the best you can prove is that $\phi(1)$ is an idempotent.

Comment: Usually unitality is part of the definition: [ring homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_homomorphism)

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh yes it is onto.

Comment: does imdempotence not imply it being unity in R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\phi: R \to R'$ is surjective, then there exists some $x \in R$ such that $\phi(x) = 1_{R'}$. Hence, observe that 
$$\phi(1_R)\cdot \phi(x) = \phi(x) = 1_{R'}$$
and obviously 
$$ \phi(x)\cdot \phi(1_R)= \phi(x) = 1_{R'}$$
where homomorphism properties were applied. Note both ways were checked, since such a check is required to verify that an element is a unit.

Therefore, $\phi(x) = 1_{R'}$ is the multiplicative inverse of $\phi(1_R)$ which makes it a unit. Note more generally that this proves that $\phi(1_R) = 1_{R'}$, since $\phi(1_R) = \phi(1_R)\cdot 1_{R'} = \phi(1_R)\cdot \phi(x) = 1_{R'}$.

**Just for your information**, this also works if $R'$ is an integral domain. In fact, if $\phi(1_R)\not= 1_{R'}$, then $\phi(1_R)$ is actually a zero divisor of $R'$ or $\phi$ is the zero map! Observe that 
$$
\phi(1_R^2) - \phi(1_R) = 0 \implies \phi(1_R)\phi(1_R) - \phi(1_R) = 0 \implies (\phi(1_R) - 1_{R'})\phi(1_R) = 0.
$$ 
If you suppose that $\phi(1_R) \not= 1_{R'}$, the only solution is if $\phi(1_R)$ is a zero divisor (it turns out $\phi(1_R) \not= 0$ unless $\phi$ is the zero map).

Suppose however that $R'$ has no zero divisors; i.e. it's an integral domain! Then we *have* to have that
$$
\phi(1_R) = 1_{R'} 
$$
and hence $\phi(1_R)$ is a unit. So this also works if $R'$ is an integral domain.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Pretty sure part of the problem is supposed to be establishing that $R'$ has an identity, not just assuming it does.  It's easy to prove, of course :)